# How to efficiently calculate co-existence of elements in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which each row show one transaction, items purchased together. Here is how my dataframe looks like

```
items
['A','B','C']
['A','C]
['C','F']
...
```

I need to create a dictionary which shows how many times items have been purchased together, something like below

```
{'A':[('B',1),('C':5)], 'B': [('A':1),('C':6)], ...}
```

Right now, I have defined a variable `freq` and then loop through my dataframe and calculate/update the dictionary (`freq`). but it's taking very long.

What's the efficient way of calculating this without looping through the dataframe?

Comment: kindly provide sample data

Comment: I did in my post

Comment: @HHH The easier you make it to get data into a dataframe, the more likely people are going to help. It's not super fun to copy what's currently posted, use `pd.from_clipboard`, then have to use `.apply(eval)` since everything was interpretied as a string, then find out that there's a missing quote, fix that, run everything again, etc... Making your data as easy as copy/paste will make people way more likely to help

Answer (score 1):

You can speed this up with sklearn's `MultiLabelBinarizer`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
```

Transform your data using:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['items']),
                   columns=mlb.classes_,
                   index=df.index)
```

to get it in the following format:

```
    A   B   C   F
0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1   1
```

And then getting you can define a trivial function like:

```
get_num_coexisting = lambda x, y: (df[x] & df[y]).sum()
```

And use as so:

```
get_num_coexisting('A', 'C')
>>> 2
```

Comment: I need to calculate the dictionary I pasted above. A dictionary which has all the frequencies. Should I just look through all the columns then to calculate it?